# How to solve listview with objects, single pane in portrait, dual pane in landscape

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-listview

Im in a picle, currently trying to learn me some Android using The Big Nerd Ranch guide.
But im having trouble understanding how i can get the app to rearrange the "detail view" from "new fragment" overlapping the listview to sidebyside view (listview left, details right).

Ive tried so many different guides and tutorials around the web now, but i guess im just to unstable in this to really figure it out. Cause all of them one way or another just ends up beeing nullpoint and so on. And im guessing that has something to do with the way the "book" builds it up vs the guides ive seen. So hopefully someone here can give me an hint.

The following code will display and listview, and when i click on an item it will replace the list fragment with another fragment displaying that item based on id from the click.
Need it to display that information next to the listview when in landscape.

SignsMainActivity.class (first to be started with: 
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SignsMainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);)

```
public class SignsMainActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new SignsMainFragment();   }}
```

SignsMainFragment.class

```
public class SignsMainFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Signs> storage;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    storage = SignStorage.get(getActivity()).getStorageOfSigns();
    SignAdapter adapter = new SignAdapter(storage);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((SignAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Signs signs = ((SignAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(SignsFragment.EXTRA_SIGNS_ID, signs.getId());
   startActivity(intent);}


private class SignAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Signs> {

    public SignAdapter(ArrayList<Signs> sSigns){
        super(getActivity(), 0, sSigns);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //If we were given a view, inflate one
        if(convertView ==null){
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sign_row, null);
        }
        //Configure the view for this Crime
        Signs signs = getItem(position);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        titleTextView.setText(signs.getName());

        return convertView;        }}}
```

SignsActivity.class

```
public class SignsActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    UUID signsId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(SignsFragment.EXTRA_SIGNS_ID);
    return SignsFragment.newInstance(signsId);}}
```

SignsFragment.class

```
public class SignsFragment extends Fragment{

public static final String EXTRA_SIGNS_ID = "signs_id";
private Signs mSign;
private TextView nameURLView;
private TextView imageURLView;
private TextView illustrationURLView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    UUID signsID = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_SIGNS_ID);
    mSign = SignStorage.get(getActivity()).getSign(signsID);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_details,parent,false);

    nameURLView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.details);
    nameURLView.setText(mSign.getName());

    return view;
}

public static SignsFragment newInstance(UUID signsId){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_SIGNS_ID, signsId);

    SignsFragment fragment = new SignsFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}}
```

SingleFragmentActivity.class (im guessing here is where i need to adjust the magic?)

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//Used to instanciate the fragment (subclasses of this class will implement the method to return an instance of the fragment that the activity is hosting)
protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
private FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_fragment);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.singleFragmentContainer);

    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.singleFragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
    }

}}
```

Storage of sign objects:

```
public class SignStorage {

private static SignStorage mSignStorage;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Signs> storageOfSigns;
private Signs signs;
private static final String TAG="xx";

private SignStorage(Context appContext){
    context = appContext;
    storageOfSigns = new ArrayList<Signs>();
    primitiveFix();
}

public static SignStorage get(Context c){
    if (mSignStorage == null){
        mSignStorage = new SignStorage(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mSignStorage;
}

public ArrayList<Signs> getStorageOfSigns() {
    return storageOfSigns;
}

public void setStorageOfSigns(ArrayList<Signs> storageOfSigns) {
    this.storageOfSigns = storageOfSigns;
}

public Signs getSign(UUID id){
    for (Signs s : storageOfSigns){
        if (s.getId().equals(id))
            return s;
    }
    return null;
}

private void primitiveFix(){

    String basePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/PictureTalk/Signs/";
    String name;
    String imageURL;
    String videoUrl;
    String illuUrl;
    Signs s;

    name = "abonnere";
    imageURL = basePath+"picture/adresse.jpg";
    videoUrl = basePath+"video/adresse.mp4";
    illuUrl = basePath+"illustrative/adresse.jpg";
    s = new Signs(name,imageURL,videoUrl,illuUrl);
    storageOfSigns.add(s);
THIS LIST GOES ON DOWNWARDS to get some items to display, will be filled later in another    
way...
```

Signs.class

```
public class Signs {

UUID id;
String name;
String videoURL;
String imageURL;
String illustrativeURL;

public Signs(String name,String videoURL,String imageURL,String illustrativeURL){
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    this.name = name;
    this.videoURL = videoURL;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
    this.illustrativeURL = illustrativeURL;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getVideoURL() {
    return videoURL;
}

public void setVideoURL(String videoURL) {
    this.videoURL = videoURL;
}

public String getBitmapURL() {
    return imageURL;
}

public void setBitmapURL(String bitmapURL) {
    this.imageURL = bitmapURL;
}

public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

acitivty_single_fragment.xml (first blank xml)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/singleFragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

sign_row.xml (xml for the listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

sign_details.xml (detail area for the object to be displayed, havent added more then textbox jet...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a list / detail screen using fragments, you want to have a single activity that contains two fragments, not two separate activities. Generally, you can think of an activity as representing a full screen.

In other words, you don't need SingleFragmentActivity or SignsActivity. Your SignsMainActivity layout XML can then have your list and details fragment side-by-side. The fragments guide has a good example of the XML:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Copying that XML and changing the names gives you a new signs_main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="SignsMainFragment"
            android:id="@+id/signs-main"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="SignsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/signs"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then set this XML as your main activity's content view:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signs_main_activity);
}
```

Comment: Ive tried a bit on that approach, including the link provided. But i think i just need to scrap the whole thing and start over following directly your approach,without trying to adapt it to the stuff i currently have. I think i have dug myself to deep of a hole with to much mess all over with the current stuff :P i mean im up in 7 classes. That cant be necessary for such an simple thing as displaying an object from an arraylist:P Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Btw would you create an different class in layout-land/ with only one fragment in the XML, or just use the same xml file and control it with the activity (im guessing that if an fragment is empty the layout weight part will not matter?)

Comment: Usually the approach would be that you have one main activity, with two XML layouts for a list-only screen and a list+details screen. For example, if you only want the list on phones, but you want list+details on tablet, you would have a version of signs_main_activity in both layout and layout-large folders. Or maybe you only want the list+details in landscape, so you would put it in layout-land. Each of these layouts would have the fragment tags, as shown in the XML...

Comment: ... The tricky part comes when you select something in the list. You have to check if the details fragment is there using getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.signs). If it is, then you can configure it with the selected item in the list. If the details fragment is not there, then you need to launch a separate activity that has only the details fragment in it. In that case it would be very similar to what you started with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for feedback. I found this tutorial that deals with the issues you explain: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture09/lecture09.html Gonna give it a try (did it earlier, but with all the old shit floating around :), starting fresh makes it easier to understand step by step)